# How to find values from list in any one of multiple columns

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a list of numeric codes (e.g. '110') and am querying a dataset which has 3 columns crm_cd, crm_cd_1, crm_cd_2... I'm trying to find any record which contains any of my codes in any of the 3 columns.

I don't understand if I'm supposed to create another col and concatenate the 3 together, or if I can query using OR statements - all I have tried have been unsuccessful (eg. giving me astronomical counts).

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| id | crm_cd | crm_cd_1 | crm_cd_2 |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
|  1 |    110 |      113 |          |
|  2 |    987 |      444 |      777 |
|  3 |    888 |      113 |      222 |
|  4 |    999 |      444 |          |
|  5 |    333 |      121 |      888 |
+----+--------+----------+----------+

    SELECT count (*)
    FROM public.crime
    WHERE date_occ >= '2017-06-01 00:00:00' 
      AND date_occ <= '2018-05-31 00:00:00'
    AND crm_cd IN ('110','113','121')
      OR crm_cd_1 IN ('110','113','121')      
      OR crm_cd_2 IN ('110','113','121');
```

Using the above example I've been trying to get records 1,3,& 5.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does `date_occ` not appear in the sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parentheses around the `crm` restrictions:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM public.crime
WHERE
    date_occ BETWEEN '2017-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-31 00:00:00' AND
    (
        crm_cd IN ('110','113','121') OR
        crm_cd_1 IN ('110','113','121') OR
        crm_cd_2 IN ('110','113','121')
    );
```

Because `AND` by default has higher precedence than `OR`, this is how your current `WHERE` clause is being evaluated:

```
WHERE
    (date_occ BETWEEN '2017-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-31 00:00:00' AND
    crm_cd IN ('110','113','121')) OR
    crm_cd_1 IN ('110','113','121') OR
    crm_cd_2 IN ('110','113','121')
```

That is, any record which matches either the `crm_cd_1` or `crm_cd_2` restriction, regardless of the date restriction, would be counted as a match.  But, your intended logic is for *both* the `crm` and date restriction to be true.

Comment: just for fun - you can use a overlap operator in postgres `WHERE .. AND (ARRAY[crm_cd, crm_cd_1, crm_cd2] && ARRAY[110,112,121])`

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way to write this is to use Postgres' array feature:

```
WHERE date_occ BETWEEN '2017-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-31 00:00:00' 
  AND array[crm_cd, crm_cd_1, crm_cd_1] && array[110,113,121];
```

The `&&` is the [overlaps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) operator and returns true if at least one value from each side matches.

It's also possible to create an index on the expression `array[crm_cd, crm_cd_1, crm_cd_1]`